# DIVIDE/AVERAGEX in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my data model I have 12 months worth of employee data and month name is in the first column, I.e Jan, Feb Mar etc

I have been using the formula below but I have an issue,

Employee 101 has worked as a sole employee in one department

2 months out of the 12, my formula below will divide that 2/12 equaling =0.16.  I want to return average headcount for the department as 1.

So only averaging for months greater 0 employees

```
DIVIDE(
AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Date Table'[Month])),
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Employee List),Employee List[Emp Status] = "Full Time")),,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

So use roundup():

```
roundup(DIVIDE( AVERAGEX( KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Date Table'[Month])), CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Employee List),Employee List[Emp Status] = "Full Time")),,""),0)
```

But you might consider wrapping it in an if() so it only rounds up when the result is less than 1.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike. Thanks for replying.  I don't feel it's a rounding issue but more about the average itself. So in excel there is an averageIF greater than 0. Sorry if I have misunderstood your message.

Answer (score 0):

I was Averagex and Divide at the same time, removing divide fixed the issue.